# Auto-updating date object in Android?

Tags: android

I'm making an embedded Android app that will be always on with an Activity that will be always alive containing views that will need to display the current date and time and update in real time.

I already have a `TextClock` for the time, is there a similar solution for date? I supposed I could have it fetch the date at regular intervals, but I'm wondering if there is a recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most common approach is to use a `TextClock` also for the date. From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock):

> `TextClock` can display the current **date** and/or time as a formatted string.

For example, if you want the date in the format `dd-MM-yyyy`, you can do this:

```xml
<TextClock
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format24Hour="dd-MM-yyyy" />
```